# Getting model item in HttpGet to HttpPost after form submission - ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, http-post, http-get

I'm having a little trouble with something.

I have an HttpGet method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Form()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.something = "hi";
    return View(model);
}
```

In my model:

```
public string something { get; set; }

[Display(Name="Something Else:")]
public string somethingelse { get; set; }
```

And in my view i have a form:

```
@model Path.To.Models.MyModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.somethingelse)

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The problem is after the form is submitted, model.something is coming back as null instead of what I expect, which is "hi"

Here's my HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(MyModel model)
{
    // model.somethingelse equals the form value, which is right
    // model.something is null, instead of what I expect - "hi"

    return View(model);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? I need to get the data from the GET to the POST after the form submission, but it's coming back null.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to put the "unchanged values" in hidden fields in your view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.something)
```

or it won't be passed !

Comment: So you have to a hidden field on the view for every filed used in the model if you want a complete model?

Comment: @CodeBlend. Well, theorically yes, but put all in hidden fields is a bad way to go. When you come in a post action, you usually just get again your entity from database, and update only the proprties you want (if you wanna update). Or better, look at ViewModels.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to submit the value of `something` along with the form, you can do this using a hidden input:

```
@model Path.To.Models.MyModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.something)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.somethingelse)

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```